# Plone 4.1 and asynchronous response

Tags: plone, wsgi, nonblocking

I'm making a Plone based social site. I want to add news feeding (like facebook feed, friend feed) into my site. This is when my people shout: "nonbloking io", "Tornado" ...

Basically, it's asynchronous response that I want: when the client call "update", the server will not response immediately, but until there is actually an update.

My friend suggest me to create a Tornado server. The client will send update request to the Tornado server, and Plone server will send the updated content to the Tornado server (using subscription), then the Tornado server response to client.

I personally think that the solution is not only overkill but also make various things (say authentication, authorization) difficult.

Can we achieve the same functionality in Plone with reasonable performance ? Do wsgi, gevent etc. helps ?

Comment: What you are describing is more like polling the server for new content. What I think might help you is to look at plone xmpp integration. Take a look at http://plone.org/products/jarn.xmpp.core and the video http://vimeo.com/30258669